# shadedraw changes color

Tags: tikz-pgf

Why does `\shadedraw` change the color cyan, and what can I do to have the same color when using `\shadedraw`?

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, shapes.arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}

\begin{document}
    
\def\ccolor{cyan}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[fill=\ccolor] (0,0) rectangle ++(2,3);

\shadedraw[top color=\ccolor, bottom color=white, draw=black] (3,0) rectangle ++(2,3);
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

gives:

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: The `cyan` color is defined as a CMYK color. The shadings use RGB color. So `cyan` is converted from CMYK to RGB...

Comment: @PaulGaborit is there any reasonable reason for that? (not so convenient for users)

Comment: @BlackMild maybe because CMYK = Cyan Magenta Yellow Black...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define your own `cyan` the way you want

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\definecolor{cyan}{RGB}{0, 255, 255}
\draw[fill=cyan] (0,0) rectangle ++(2,3);
\shadedraw[top color=cyan, bottom color=white, draw=black] (3,0) rectangle ++(2,3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

or you can use the RGB color model throughout the document

```
\documentclass[tikz, rgb, border=1cm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[fill=cyan] (0,0) rectangle ++(2,3);
\shadedraw[top color=cyan, bottom color=white, draw=black] (3,0) rectangle ++(2,3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Two cyan rectangles where one is shaded]

-or the CMYK model `\documentclass[tikz, cmyk, border=1cm]{standalone}`

[image: Two dark cyan rectangles where one is shaded]